# Uploading issue with IE, works properly for mozilla

Tags: php, html, upload

td>

Above is working fine for Mozilla and not for IE

PHP:  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
       {
          header("Location: EHP_Configuration.html");
       }

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's the broken table cell in HTML.  You said `td>`.

Beyond that, I don't know what script you're using but you should really find a way to not put your max file size limit as a hidden field (or anywhere on the client-side), as this is a security risk.